# Replace commas with <br> in CSS

Tags: css

We are using a CRM database which is accessed from a web console front-end. One of the merge fields retrieved from the database is the site address, which is returned as a one-line string separated by commas instead of the address format used for mailing addresses.

That is, instead of:

> 45 Seafield Place
>   FORT WILLIAM
>   PH33 4XJ

...it inserts:

> 45 Seafield Place, FORT WILLIAM, PH33 4XJ

As a proprietary product, we have no access to the configuration of the web server or the ability to modify the PHP used to generate the pages within it. The templates for customer letters are fully customisable and are simple HTML, with a `@media print` CSS block to control the styling when letters are printed straight from the browser (similar to Google Docs).

As I cannot control the content or make use of JavaScript/JQuery to perform text replacement, is there any way CSS can replace each comma within a class with a `<br>` tag?

Comment: How come you can use CSS but not Javascript?

Comment: css cant replace anything. the only way you can do it is with javascript. note that javascript files are mere text files same as css, so if you can edit/add one you most definitely can edit/add the other as well.

Comment: Is the address contain inside an element on its own? If so you might be able to play with `white-space` property and the `width` of the element to make them collapse into place.

Comment: @gillesc good idea, although it will not rid of the commas

Comment: @EfrainReyes I can't use JavaScript because it gets automatically stripped from the HTML by the database front-end when I save a letter template to the systme. Only HTML and CSS are permitted (as internal CSS in the Style tag or inline, but not as an external stylesheet).

Comment: there is no reason you could not use JS ***unless*** it's a requirement for the javascript-disabled clients.

Comment: @gillesc Yes, the address is inside an element of its own.

Comment: @Banana I don't mind if the commas aren't removed, just so long as the string can be displayed as a multi-line address.

Comment: how does it strip the javascript? does it remove anything inside `<script>` tags or...? because you can simply add an `onLoad=''` attribute to the `<body>` and write your entire javascript code inside the attribute...

Comment: don't believe in the so-called `white-space`, it's not easy to hack with it, it depends much on the HTML structure, suppose if the text is contained just in 1 element, how could it break the lines right at the comma positions? The only way to solve this problem is ***javascript***, if you can't use it, then I can surely say that you ***can't*** solve the problem (so just feel free to be satisfied with the current result, no way out without JS).

Comment: Okay, so I'll concede that this cannot be done in CSS, and the database admin console is overly strict when it comes to preventing me sneaking any non-HTML/CSS code in there. When I attempt text replacement using JavaScript and save the HTML letter template to the database, any `<script>` blocks get stripped automatically, as does the `<body onLoad="...">` attribute (containing in-line code or otherwise).

Comment: CSS can't solve this and you can't add JS code... Do you have access to the database itself, not via the web console of course but via a cron task directly on the server or something?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the only way to achieve this is using javascript.

 since your server strips all javascript from the page, you have to 'trick' it and add javascript that it will not strip.

i believe it can be done by putting your javascript code into an `onload` attribute of your body element, this way the server will not see it as javascript but rather just an attribute and will leave it be.

```
<body onload="var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');spans[0].innerHTML=spans[0].innerHTML.replace(/,/g,'<br/>');">
    <span>
        45 Seafield Place, FORT WILLIAM, PH33 4XJ
    </span>

</body>
```

<kbd>**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/JZMZM/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE**

you can even strip the javascript code yourself after executing it:

```
<body onload="var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');spans[0].innerHTML=spans[0].innerHTML.replace(/,/g,'<br/>'); document.getElementsByTagName(
'body')[0].removeAttribute('onload');">
    <span>
        45 Seafield Place, FORT WILLIAM, PH33 4XJ
    </span>

</body>
```

<kbd>**[2nd Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/JZMZM/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: how could the OP insert this into the HTML? looks like he can't access or determine HTML code, he can't inject the JS normally. It appears to me that he can only modify the CSS. So looks like he is actually limited to what CSS can do.

Comment: " The templates for customer letters are fully customisable and are simple HTML"  **and**  " I can't use JavaScript because it gets automatically stripped from the HTML"

Comment: therefore unless the server's JS stripping algorithm is clever (which i highly doubt) he should be able to pull it off by using my way

Comment: well I missed that out, looks like his problem is still solvable because at least we have a way to inject code into HTML (although it's filtered by server before actually becoming HTML code).

Comment: i strongly believe the server's filtering process is not perfect. i dont think someone would code a simple mailing application with such a high security, after all, its a system which is being used by the employees and not by the customers. there must be a way to 'smuggle' javascript into it. he should really try inserting it into the onload tag first though.

Comment: This would work perfectly if it weren't for the admin section of the database automatically stripping out `<script>` and `<body onLoad="...">`.

Comment: @Banana I don't think this is about security per se, just the devs who created the database front-end wanting to limit the customisation so as to keep it running stable.

Comment: @Kryz yes i understand, but most just dont bother restricting it too much. im sure there is a way to bypass it